# Change Canvas.Left property in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind, attached-properties

I have a rectangle in my XAML and want to change its `Canvas.Left` property in code behind:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Second90.Page"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Width="400" Height="300" KeyDown="txt_KeyDown">
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle 
            Name="theObject" 
            Canvas.Top="20" 
            Canvas.Left="20" 
            Width="10" 
            Height="10" 
            Fill="Gray"/>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

But this doesn't work:

```
private void txt_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    theObject.Canvas.Left = 50;
}
```

Does anyone know what the syntax is to do this?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

```
Canvas.SetLeft(theObject, 50)
```

Comment: +1, gotta love type safety.  I am curious though why SetLeft takes a UIElement instead of a DependencyObject

Comment: @JaredPar: at a guess I would say that since SetLeft is specifically a method of Canvas it understands what types it would make sense give a Left property to.  It deems this to be UIElement, this perhaps increases the detection of faulty code where accidentally the wrong variable is passed to it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.left.aspx Canvas.Left is an attached property, which supports a XAML usage. When setting this property in code, use SetLeft instead.

Answer (score 57):

Try this

```
theObject.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 50d);
```

There is a group of methods on DependencyObject (base of most WPF classes) which allow the common access to all dependency properties.  They are

- SetValue
- GetValue
- ClearValue

**Edit** Updated the set to use a double literal since the target type is a double.

Comment: Thanks, to get this to work I had to cast the integer: theObject.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)50);

Comment: No, for this specify numeric constant in double format:
heObject.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 50.0);

Answer (score 12):

As we are changing the property of the 'object', it would be better to use method suggedte by JaredPar:

```
theObject.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 50d);
```