# How can I bind ComboBox.TextBlock in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I'm trying to convert some XAML to C# code. Here's the xaml:

```
<ComboBox TextBlock.Foreground="{Binding DesiredForegroundBrush}"/>
```

I'd like to do the same thing in C# code, but I'm at a loss on how to access the TextBlock.

I tried the following:

```
 ComboBoxInstance.TextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, "DesiredForegroundBrush");
```

But the TextBlock is not accessible in C# code.

I also tried getting to the child of the combo box, but the GetChildrenCount returns 0:

```
 var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(ComboBoxInstance);
```

I did a few web searches but all I found was questions about how to bind combo boxes to TextBoxes.

I feel like there has to be an easy way to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Update:

I have found this post:

[How to I access an attached property in code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541420/how-to-i-access-an-attached-property-in-code-behind)

But that only shows how to directly assign the property in the code behind, as opposed to set up binding on it.

Comment: You can try `comboBoxTest.SetBinding( TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, new Binding( "DesiredForegroundBrush" ) );` Are there some problems with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ComboBox.ForegroundProperty` to bind the foreground Color. Why do you want the textbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Every control derived from "Control" class will have Foreground property which is a dependency property and could be bound to any **Brush** value. To change the value of any control foreground we don't need to dig for the property.

```
<ComboBox Background="{Binding ForegroundColorBrush}"/>
```

and combobox foreground color will change according to binding.